# Email about bounty

Tags: bug, bounty

I offered a bounty on a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528769/absolutely-irreducible-representations-of-the-absolute-galois-group-of-q-p) that isn't "mine". Today I got, what looks to be, an automatically generated email saying:

> **Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!**
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> **Absolutely irreducible representations
> of the absolute Galois group of Q_p** … ended and will be auto-closed
> after the 24-hour grace period expires. Thanks for putting a bounty on
> your question. It looks like there are still no answers yet. You
> should consider improving your question to attract more answers. Could
> you:
>
> - add more text describing the problem?
> - add or change the tags?
> - update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?
>
> Once you get answers, please review them. If you feel one of them
> deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left
> of the answer. Otherwise, you might consider providing feedback in the
> form of comments or edits. If you don't award your bounty, the highest
> scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty
> started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount. For more
> information, refer to the bounty faq.

I am guessing that this generated email should be updated.

Comment: What would you suggest; would changing "your question" to "this question" (2 occurrences) be enough?

Comment: @robjohn: That would be a start. But, I would also say that the email shouldn't suggest how I can change the question.

Comment: So "you might consider" vs "you should consider"?

Comment: @robjohn: I probably wasn't clear enough. I offered a bounty on a question that I didn't ask and I just wanted to point out how this email says that it is my question. So I guess the email should change the "your question" to "this question". But I am not sure if it appropriate for the email to suggest me to "add text describing the problem" or to "update the title..." (since the question isn't mine).

Comment: That is why I suggested the changes I did. I was trying to make the language more generic, so that it might apply to anyone offering a bounty. Although editing questions of others is restricted to users with at least 2000 reputation, edits can be suggested by users with less reputation. However, if someone is interested enough in the answer to offer a bounty, it is not unreasonable to think they might be interested in improving the question in order to get an answer.

Comment: @robjohn: Ok, that makes sense. If you want I can make a full suggestion on how to change the email...

Comment: That would be a good thing to do. Hopefully, a developer or Community Team member will read this soon. I will try to get their attention.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that this email is a generic one sent out for all bounties offered on questions. I welcome other suggestions for how to change the email, but I suggest having two slightly different emails: one for bounties offered on one's own questions and one for bounties offered on other peoples questions. The email about one's own questions isn't changed and the email about bounties offered on other people's questions is changed to:

I suggest changing the email to:

> **Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!**
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> **[Question title with link]**
>
> … ended and will be auto-closed
> after the 24-hour grace period expires. Thanks for putting a bounty on
> $\color{green}{\text{this question}}$. It looks like there are still no answers yet. $\color{green}{\text{Even though you are not the original poster, please consider editing the question}}$. Could
> you:
>
> - $\color{green}{\text{add what you have tried as a new section to the question?}}$
> - $\color{green}{\text{A}}$dd or change the tags?
> - $\color{green}{\text{U}}$pdate the title to more accurately reflect the issue?
>
> $\color{green}{\text{Please limit your changes of the original text as given.  If you add details or}}$ $\color{green}{\text{your attempt or thoughts, then please make it clear that you are not the OP.}}$
> $\color{green}{\text{If}}$ you get answers, please review them. If you feel one of them
> deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left
> of the answer. Otherwise, you might consider providing feedback in the
> form of comments or edits. If you don't award your bounty, the highest
> scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty
> started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount. For more
> information, refer to the bounty faq.

The text in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ are changes. I didn't manage to get the same formatting as in the email.